# Solution for the recurrence

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, recurrence

I am looking for the solution of this recurrence. Basically I want to learn how to solve this kind of recurrence and how to get its value.

T(N) = 3T(N/3) + T(N/2) + N

Comment: If you want an asymptotic for T, not solving, see [Akra-Bazzi-Leighton Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method). Using it you obtain that T is in Theta(n^r) where r ≈ 1.42431983923747... is the solution of 1 = 3^(1-r)+2^(-r).

Comment: [Here is a link to Leighton's paper](https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.046/spring04/handouts/akrabazzi.pdf), which contains the proof.

Comment: You can find it exactly using the method conditional method linked, and you can also bound it more easily (in the cost of being much less precise) by noticing T(N) <= 4T(N/2)+N -> T(N) = O(N^2)

Answer (score 0):

Using Akra-Bazzi method is definitely a great solution.

## The below solution about recurrence tree is wrong. Find why in the comments.

Just want to left the **wrong** solution here in case someone is curious or makes the same error.

Here is a solution from recurrence tree.

For level h, it will look like

T(N) = 3^h*T(N/3^h) + T(N/2^h) + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{h-1} (3^{i-1} + 3^i)*T(N/(3^i 2^{h-i}))

which means level h contributes

N < N + N/2^h + 4N/3 * (1-\frac{1}{2^{h-1}}) < 4N

And notice that, the height of the recurrence tree is between

(\log_2 N, \log_3 N)

Thus, the big-Oh notation is

O(N log N)

( Just want to illustrate that recurrence tree is a possible solution.

Comment: You should check your argument, since it must be wrong. Akra-Bazzi's theorem shows that T is in Theta(n^r) for r approximately 1.42..., which is larger than 1. Such a function cannot be in O(nlog(n))

Comment: Since your estimation is a smaller growth, the problem must be that you are under-counting somewhere.

Comment: Your are right. I double checked the process, but didn't find the wrong place. I will leave the answer here. Maybe someone could point out.

Comment: What the tree method does is to express T(N) in terms of some T(x)'s for some x's in, say, [0,1]. One composes the recurrence with itself until all terms are some T(x) for x in [0,1] and then counts the terms, which depends on the number of compositions of the recurrence (the level of the tree), which in turns depends on N. The problem in your analysis is that the terms N/3^h N/2^h and the mixed N/(2^k3^(h-k)) get to the interval [0,1] at different times h for a general N. In the tree analogy they don't belong to the same level of the tree.

Comment: Here's my understanding. Taking the height = log_2 N, it under estimates the result, while taking the height = log_3 N, it over estimates the result. Both coverage at O(NlogN). I think it's the squeeze theorem. In your explanation, if I understand correctly, it seems that it might over-estimate the answer because it takes a constant contribution N for each level and the height is over estimated. However, the result is under-estimate.

Comment: Well, note that the level h in your argument is the first time that N/3^h is in [0,1]. This means that other terms like T(N/2^h) some hard-to describe group of the form T(N/(3^i2^(h-i))) still need to be expanded further using the recurrence. These would provide further terms in your sum, which explains the under counting.

Comment: Ah! And take into account that in your argument you are not really raking h=log_2(N). That cannot be the case since T(N/3^h) would have had an argument N/3^h in [0,1] long before that h, for some k << h. This means that the term 3^kT(N/3^k) would have had to stay there, since you can't use the recurrence on it any further.

Comment: I still can't understand you. If I understand correctly, your first reply shows the under estimates, which is the lower bound, which is N * log_3 N. Your second reply shows the over estimates, which is the upper bound, which is 4N * log_2 N. Both bound make sense if the expansion of T(N) at level h is right, which means the contribution of each level is less than 4N. And hey all say the result is O(N log N), which is the squeeze theorem. I think there might be some errors on the upper bound, but still not knowing why.

Comment: '*if the expansion of T(N) at level h is right*'. Well, it is right on its own, but what I have been saying all this time is that it is not the right expression that one uses in that 'tree argument'. For the tree argument all the terms in the formula must be *initial terms*. For example, terms T(x) with x in [0,1], or some other *fixed* interval. That is what your formula for T(N) doesn't satisfy.

Comment: You could choose h such that T(N/3^h) is for sure an *initial term* of the sequence, but then some of the other terms in your expression for T(N) are not initial yet. They still need to be expanded using the recurrence.

Comment: Just compare to the argument for a simpler recurrence in which the tree thing does work. T(n)=2T(n/3)+n. When you expand T(n) all the terms become *initial terms* (leaves of the tree) at the same time, because all of them are of the same form T(n/3^n). You need initial terms only, because those are the ones that you know are bounded by a constant. Then the bound that you obtain for T(n) is that constant times the number of terms in the expansion (multiplied by its coefficients). But the fact that all terms in the expansion are initial terms is *crucial*.